# Map View model and data model with auto mapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I want to use auto mapper to map my Data Model to my View Model.

This is my class:

PersonViewModel.cs (same as my data Model):

```
public class PersonViewModel {
    public PersonViewModel(Person personDataModel) //I want to create map here of my PersonListDisplayModel with Person.cs(data model).
    {
        PersonListDisplayModel = new List<PersonListDisplayModel>();
    }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public List<PersonListDisplayModel> PersonListDisplayModel { get; set; }
}

public class PersonListDisplayModel {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

My View:

```
@model PersonViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm("","",FormMethod.Post)){
//here i will add records
}
@Html.Partial("_personList", Model.PersonListDisplayModel) //Here i will load my partial view to display list of person but how do i pass here like this:Model.PersonListDisplayModel
```

This is my Controller:

```
public ActionResult Save() {
    PersonViewModel model = new PersonViewModel();
    using (var db = new MyDBContext()) {
        var data = db.Person.tolist();
        return View();
    }    
}
```

**Note**: **I want to create map in my View model only and not in controller**.

Comment: It should be done in the controller not the model and since you don't have a parameterless constructor this will throw an exception when you submit anyway

Comment: so there is no way that i can create this map in my model only.you can change my constructor.

Comment: I'm just saying it should be done in the controller (not sure why you don't want to follow normal practice)

Comment: @StephenMuecke:ok so can you show me how to do in the controller and if it can be done in the model too then please show me both the codes if possible for you.

Comment: Suggest you read the 3 articles on [this blog](http://cpratt.co/page/4/)

Comment: @StephenMuecke:Thanks.i would definetely read the articles provided in the link but still apart from this any solution would be very good for me

Comment: Obviously you can map anywhere you like. But are you asking for the actual mapping action to take place in the view model. Because mapping is done in two parts, the profile is created which defines how to map and then there is the mapping which is the action undertaken to transform the object to another

Comment: @LacyJones, SO is not a code writing service. Do some research, have a go, and if your still having problems, post your code and then we can help.

Comment: @CallumLinington:can you please give me any idea of how to do this or post any solution from which i can get idea.

Comment: On this occasion I would honestly have to agree with @StephenMuecke there are plenty of examples on the web, even the AutoMapper repo on github has plenty of examples